# Lightning-datatable tick all checkboxes on page load

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

When I load and open a page the checkboxes are not ticked.
[image]

Please advise how to tick all checkboxes on page load so when I open the page all of the checkboxes to be ticked by default?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots, but please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/367942/edit) your question to also add what code you have tried so far (it's OK if it doesn't work) and exactly (e.g., exact error text, details of unexpected behavior) how it is not working. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.")*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `selected-rows` attribute of the `ightning-datatable`. You'd need to prepopulate all the ids in a field at load time then, bind `selected-rows` to that field. The component will show all the rows selected.

Example:

*html*

```
<template>
    <h2> Account Datatable</h2>
    <template if:true={accList}>
        <lightning-datatable data={accList} columns={columns} key-field="Id" selected-rows={preSelectedRows}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
    <template if:true={error}>
        {error}
    </template>
</template>
```

*JavaScript*

```
...............
...............
    @wire(getAccountList)
    wiredAccounts({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.accList = data;
            let my_ids = [];
            this.accList.forEach(function (acc, index) {
                my_ids.push(acc.Id);
            });
            my_ids.push(this.accList[1].Id);
            this.preSelectedRows = my_ids;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
...............
...............
```